# Practical benefits of new advice system in Emacs 24.4

Tags: emacs24.4, advice

Emacs 24.4 comes with a new advice system. The `NEWS` file says:

> ** New package `nadvice.el` offers lighter-weight advice facilities.
>   It is layered as:
>
> *** `add-function`/`remove-function`, which can be used to add/remove code on
>   any function-carrying place, such as process filters or `<foo>-function` hooks.
>
> *** `advice-add`/`advice-remove` to add/remove a piece of advice on a named
>   function, much like `defadvice` does.

**Q:** What are the practical benefits and implications of this new package?

I am especially interested in answers addressing the following points:

- If I am only using advice to customize Emacs (as opposed to writing add-on packages), do I need to switch to the new system? Will it replace the old system at some point?
- What *exactly* can I do with the new system that I can't accomplish with `defadvice`?
- What is the significance of being able to "add/remove code on any function-carrying place"?

Answer (score 59):

The new advice system has the following advantages:

- `add-function`: This is brand new functionality that simply was not part of defadvice.  It is a kind of hybrid between `add-hook` and `defadvice`.  In the future, expect more `foo-function` variables (modified via `add-function`) and less `foo-functions` (modified via `add-hook`).  This functionality was the main motivation to implement the new advice system, triggered by a bug report asking how to "share" a process-filter between different packages.
- Implementation simplicity: once `add-function` was implemented, it takes only 8KB to implement the `advice-add` functionality which brings pretty much all the functionality of the 100KB of advice.el.
- Design simplicity: defadvice has various notions that are generally difficult to understand precisely and/or rarely used.  E.g. the difference between "enabling" and "activating" advices.  Or the meaning of "pre" and/or "compiled".  There are also quirks in the handling of `ad-do-it`, such as the fact that it looks like a variable-reference rather than a call, or the fact that you need to `(setq ad-return-value ...)` explicitly rather than simply returning the value.
- Defadvice suffers from various problems w.r.t macroexpansion and compilation: the body of an advice is not exposed as "code" (which the compiler and macroexpander see) but as "data" which is later on combined to make up an expression.  So macroexpansion happens late (which can causes surprises if you use things like `(eval-when-compile (require 'foo))`) and lexical-scoping is hard to preserve correctly.

As for whether you need to switch to the new system: I do intend to get rid of the old defadvice at some point in the future, but I think this future is relatively distant (and it'll first have to move to `lisp/obsolete`, then later to GNU ELPA).

Comment: Do plans exist to add to nadvice.el the same argument-modification functionality offered by the old advice system?

Comment: No, that pretty much makes no sense in the context of nadvice.el where the advice functions are plain old normal functions.  But you can use `:around` advice (or `:filter-args` or `:filter-result` advice) to get the same effect.

Comment: I can't, though. Suppose I want to advise a function of two arguments, replacing only the second argument, so that the advised function will still prompt according to its interactive form for the first one. New advice seems to provide a couple of different ways to *replace* an advised function's interactive form, but I don't see anything offering more nuance than that.

Comment: @AaronMiller: Please make it a separate SX question, so it can be discussed without the artificial limits of SX comments.

Comment: Done, at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19233/2162. I appreciate your following up. (I'd also be curious to see the bug report you mention in your answer, but haven't been able to find it via Google or mailing list archive search. Do you mind linking it?)

Comment: Good question.  I can't find the original thread either.  The closest I could find is a later discussion which also mentions the original one: http://debbugs.gnu.org/17361

Comment: @AaronMiller: Regarding your question at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19233/2162, I don't see it mention any *interactive* argument.

Answer (score 9):

One of the clear benefits of advice being normal functions is that you can visit a definition with `find-function`.

At present, when viewing the help for a (new-style) advised function, it provides a link to the help for the advice function, and from there a link to the source (as usual for function help).

The old system provided the advice docstring inline, but there was no way to see the code (I usually resorted to `rgrep`).

(Personally I'd like to see a blend of the old and new approaches to displaying the help, as I liked having the inline docstring, but I'm sure that's possible down the track.)

Comment: Yes, it is too bad that the new advice system does not let you add to the existing doc string like `defadvice` does. See [this Emacs bug report](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=14734). This is shortcoming.

Answer (score 8):

From the file header:

```
;;; Commentary:

;; This package lets you add behavior (which we call "piece of advice") to
;; existing functions, like the old `advice.el' package, but with much fewer
;; bells and whistles.
```

As I read it, the primary goal is to be simpler than the old advice system, not to have more capabilities. Reading the docs, it seems that `advice-add` contains a subset of `defadvice`'s functionality, while `add-function` contains some nice functionality for advising non-traditional functions such as process filters (which was probably possible with `defadvice`, but I'm not sure how).

As far as I know, `defadvice` is not officially deprecated so you should feel free to keep using it for now (and if you're a package author, you probably want to keep using it until 24.4 becomes more widely adopted). However, it sounds like the Emacs authors want to migrate completely to the new system eventually, so it probably makes sense to slowly switch over.

Comment: See also: [Adapting code using the old defadvice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Porting-old-advices.html#Porting-old-advices)

Comment: Yes. The new is different, not more. And yes, there is a lot of use of `defadvice` out there (and there will continue to be).

Answer (score 1):

One thing I haven't seen mentioned here -- though in some ways it is due to the simpler approach (better modularity and "glue") of the "new" advice system, which *has* been mentioned in other answers -- is this: it is much *easier to add, combine, remove, reorder*, etc. nadvice advice.

It's even possible to do so interactively, dynamically, though nadvice needs a little help to facilitate this.
I'm not aware of other use of nadvice this way (interactive composition of advice), but there is at least one such application. I make use of it in [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus), to let you add and remove combinations of arbitrary Isearch filter predicates (filters) while searching.

IOW, just as you change your search pattern incrementally, so you can refine your search on the fly using multiple filters.

Isearch filtering is done using variable `isearch-filter-predicate`, which has been available for quite a while now. Yet Isearch filters are not defined often. They are typically static and predefined for a given context (e.g. Wdired). It's not very easy for users to define and use them, interactively at least.

There is only *one* variable, `isearch-filter-predicate`, so changing filtering really means changing *the* single filter predicate, which amounts to composing functions, combining predicates, to narrow, expand, or otherwise modify the search.

But that's exactly what nadvice is good at. In sum, nadvice is so handy for combining functions that it can make it easy to *interactively* refine search filtering.
(See [Dynamic Isearch Filtering](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicIsearchFiltering) for more about this.)