# Python mode - bypassing dialogue on C-c C-c, and having Python appear in its own frame

Tags: python

Whenever I'm in Python mode and do `C-c C-c`, I have to answer two questions - firstly, what command to run (which defaults to `/usr/bin/python2 -i` for me) and secondly, whether I want a dedicated process. However, I want these things to be the same all the time (namely, use `/usr/bin/python2 -i` and *not* create a dedicated process), and don't want to have to tell Emacs this explicitly every time. How do I set it up so that these are defaults for `C-c C-c`, and won't require me to tell Emacs anything extra to just pressing `C-c C-c`?

Also, I would like to have Python start in a pop-up frame after the first call to `C-c C-c`. I tried code like this:

```
(setq display-buffer-alist
  (quote (("\\*Python\\*" display-buffer-pop-up-frame
     (nil)))))
```

However, this doesn't seem to affect the `*Python*` I get from `C-c C-c`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C-c C-c` is bound to `python-shell-send-buffer` by default. Normally, you'd run this command *after* creating a Python process via <kbd>C-c C-p</kbd> (`run-python`), which will *not* prompt for anything by default.

If you always want to be able to hit <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>, irrespective of whether there is a Python process or not, you can advise `python-shell-send-buffer` as follows<sup>1</sup>:

```el
(defun python-shell-send-buffer-no-prompt (&optional arg)
  (python-shell-get-or-create-process "/usr/bin/python -i" nil t))

(advice-add 'python-shell-send-buffer :before #'python-shell-send-buffer-no-prompt)
```

In conjunction with the code you posted, this also takes care of popping to a new frame and displaying the `*Python*` buffer there when it is first created: As the signature of `python-shell-get-or-create-process` indicates, the last argument specifies whether the `*Python*` buffer should be shown or not:

```el
(python-shell-get-or-create-process &optional CMD DEDICATED SHOW)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This code was written to make use of the [new advice system introduced in Emacs 24.4](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3079/504). If you are using an earlier version of Emacs, the following code will work:

```el
(defadvice python-shell-send-buffer
    (before python-shell-send-buffer-no-prompt (&optional arg) activate compile)
  (python-shell-get-or-create-process "/usr/bin/python -i" nil t))
```

Comment: It seems my .emacs doesn't like it very much: it claims that ``advice-add`` function definition is void. Should I call this after or before a particular thing?

Comment: @KozRoss Try using the `defadvice` version of the code I just added to my answer.

Comment: I've got a *very* odd error message:

``python-shell-send-buffer: Wrong number of arguments: #[nil "ÆÇ!ÈÉ\"ÆÊ!ÈÉ
\"Ë !Ë!Ì2``

Comment: @KozRoss That must be coming from customizations in your init-file. I tested both versions of the code in `emacs -Q` (Emacs version 24.4), and it is working for me.