# Remove Org-mode tags from ASCII but not LaTeX export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm aware of `#+OPTIONS: tags:nil` to have tags not be exported. I'd like them exported to LaTeX exports, but not ASCII exports. Is there a way to have options only apply to certain exports? Is there some other method to have ASCII export drop tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by [advising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) the commands that serve as entry points for the different export back-ends offered by `org-mode`. For example, to tell `org-mode` to skip tags when exporting to ASCII, you can advise the command for exporting to ASCII (`org-ascii-export-to-ascii`) as follows:

```el
(defadvice org-ascii-export-to-ascii
    (around turn-off-tags (&optional async subtreep visible-only
                                     body-only ext-plist) activate compile)
  (let ((org-export-with-tags nil))
    ad-do-it))
```

Note that Emacs 24.4 introduces a [new advice system](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3079/504) which might replace the old system at some point in the future. Here is a modified version of the code above that makes use of the new advice system (use this version if you are already on Emacs 24.4 and want to future-proof your configuration):

```el
(defun turn-off-tags
    (orig &optional async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist)
  (let ((org-export-with-tags nil))
    (funcall orig async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist)))

(advice-add 'org-ascii-export-to-ascii :around #'turn-off-tags)
```

### Generalizing the solution

The general naming scheme for export commands that produce files is `org-<backend>-export-to-<backend>`:

- `org-ascii-export-to-ascii`
- `org-html-export-to-html`
- `org-latex-export-to-latex`
- ...

Here is a skeleton that you can use to set as many `<backend>`-specific options as you like:

```el
(defadvice org-<backend>-export-to-<backend>
    (around org-<backend>-set-export-options
            (&optional async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist)
            activate compile)
  (let ((<variable> <value>)
        (<variable> <value>)
        (<variable> <value>))
    ad-do-it))
```

Ported to the new advice system:

```el
(defun org-<backend>-set-export-options
    (orig &optional async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist)
  (let ((<variable> <value>)
        (<variable> <value>)
        (<variable> <value>))
    (funcall orig async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist)))

(advice-add 'org-<backend>-export-to-<backend>
            :around #'org-<backend>-set-export-options)
```

Comment: @mankoff Did you get a chance to try out this solution? Let me know if you have any follow-up questions.

Answer (score 1):

Recall macros are expanded before the document is parsed.  This might get you started.

```
#+MACRO: tags-on-latex (eval (format "#+OPTIONS: tags:%s" (if (org-export-derived-backend-p org-export-current-backend 'latex) "t" "nil")))
{{{tags-on-latex}}}
* h                                                                     :tag:
```

For more fine-grained control (say html) just add more backend to the `&rest` part of  `org-export-derived-backend-p`.