# How do I use nadvice?

Tags: advice, emacs-internals, elisp

My config is full of advice, and I keep hearing about the new shiny minimalist `nadvice.el` package.

I've searched the manuals, and I've read the [source](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/emacs-lisp/nadvice.el), but I'll openly admit: *I still have no idea how to actually use it.*

Can anyone here point me to a guide, or tell me how to get started porting my old-style advice over?

Comment: +1 for the question. If you've searched the manuals and not found what you needed, please consider filing a (doc) bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Some developers sometimes prefer developing over documenting. ;-) It is important that Emacs document itself.

Comment: The manual actually has a section on that, see [(info "(elisp) Porting old advices")](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Porting-old-advices.html#Porting-old-advices). It's not listed in the detailed index for whatever reason though.

Comment: Closely related: [Practical benefits of new advice system in Emacs 24.4](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3079/504)

Comment: Few examples using `nadvice` from my config: [:after](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/6079fb2b0cdcf70452d4d110d85f27826a4899a2/setup-files/setup-editing.el#L679-L690), [:filter-return](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/6079fb2b0cdcf70452d4d110d85f27826a4899a2/setup-files/setup-undo-tree.el#L17-L19), [:around](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/6079fb2b0cdcf70452d4d110d85f27826a4899a2/setup-files/setup-deft.el#L28-L32), [:before-until](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/6079fb2b0cdcf70452d4d110d85f27826a4899a2/setup-files/setup-verilog.el#L348-L367)

Comment: @wasamasa I'm afraid that section is far from complete. I have a few advices (maybe just one, we'll see) that are more complex. Should I just make a question for each here?

Comment: Adding to @kaushalmodi's list, here is a [:filter-args](https://github.com/Archenoth/dotemacs/blob/b888a73bab8859bbd4e3201f294a2baa781a3346/Archenoth-config.org#the-actual-style-logic) from my config. It essentially lets me change arguments that a function gets called with before the function runs. The `(list buffer-or-name action frame)` list at the end of `my-display-buffer` are the arguments that the advised `display-buffer` gets called with in the end.

Comment: Have you seen [the section on porting to nadvice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Porting-old-advices.html#Porting-old-advices)?

Comment: It's at best incomplete. At worst, it's just confusing. It doesn't explain what happens to `ad-return-value`, `ad-do-it`, and `ad-get-orig-definition`, among other nuances.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

All information you need is included in `C-h f add-function` which
describes the underlying mechanism of `advice-add`.

The new advice system basically acts like replacing the current
definition of a function by the function described in the table in
`C-h f add-function`, depending on your choice of the `WHERE`
argument, only cleaner for the sake of tracking what behaviour has
been defined in what source file.

### An example with the `:around` option

The most general case is the `:around` option, so I give an example
for that. (It is probably better to use dedicated `WHERE` parameters
when possible, but you can replace every other by an equivalent
`:around` function).

Just as an example, lets say you want to debug some use of `find-file`
and want to `print` its argument list every time it is called. You
could write

```
(defun my-find-file-advice-print-arguments (old-function &rest arguments)
  "Print the argument list every time the advised function is called."
  (print arguments)
  (apply old-function arguments))

(advice-add #'find-file :around #'my-find-file-advice-print-arguments)
```

With this new implementation, everything the advice needs is passed as
argument. `ad-get-args` becomes unnecessary, because the arguments are
passed to the advice function as normal function arguments (for
`WHERE` arguments for which it makes sense). `ad-do-it` becomes
unnecessary as `:around` advice gets as arguments the function and the
arguments, so `(ad-do-it)` is replaced by the form

```
(apply old-function arguments)
```

or when you have named the arguments

```
(funcall old-function first-arg second-arg)
```

which is cleaner as there are no magic forms involved. Modifying the
arguments simply happens by passing modified values to `OLD-FUNCTION`.

### Other `WHERE` values

The docstring of `add-function` contains a table of all advice places (or "combinators"),
and what they are equivalent to, and explains the functionality in
terms of a `lambda` behaving equivalent to the advised function:

```
`:before'       (lambda (&rest r) (apply FUNCTION r) (apply OLDFUN r))
`:after'        (lambda (&rest r) (prog1 (apply OLDFUN r) (apply FUNCTION r)))
`:around'       (lambda (&rest r) (apply FUNCTION OLDFUN r))
`:override'     (lambda (&rest r) (apply FUNCTION r))
`:before-while' (lambda (&rest r) (and (apply FUNCTION r) (apply OLDFUN r)))
`:before-until' (lambda (&rest r) (or  (apply FUNCTION r) (apply OLDFUN r)))
`:after-while'  (lambda (&rest r) (and (apply OLDFUN r) (apply FUNCTION r)))
`:after-until'  (lambda (&rest r) (or  (apply OLDFUN r) (apply FUNCTION r)))
`:filter-args'  (lambda (&rest r) (apply OLDFUN (funcall FUNCTION r)))
`:filter-return'(lambda (&rest r) (funcall FUNCTION (apply OLDFUN r)))

(cited from `C-h f add-function')
```

where FUNCTION is the advice function and OLDFUN the function where
the advice is added. Don't try to understand all of them at once, just
select a `WHERE` symbol that sounds fitting and try to understand that
one.

Or just use `:around`. As far as I can tell the only advantage of
using specialized `WHERE`s over `:around` for everything is that you
get a bit more information from looking up `C-h f ADVISED-FUNCTION`
prior to reading the docstring of the advice. Unless you plan to
publish the code containing the advice it probably doesn't matter.

### Named advice functions

I recommend using named functions as advice since it provides many
advantages (some of them also apply to using named functions for hooks):

- It shows up in `C-h f find-file` as

  ```
  :around advice: `my-find-file-advice-print-arguments'
  ```

  linking to the definition of the advice function, which as usual
  contains a link to the file where it was defined . If the advice
  had been defined as a `lambda` form directly in the `advice-add`
  form the docstring would be shown inline (a mess for long
  docstrings?) and nothing would indicate where it was defined.
- You can remove the advice with

  ```
  (advice-remove #'find-file #'my-find-file-advice-print-arguments)
  ```
- You can update the definition of the advice without rerunning
  `advice-add` or risking to keep the old version active (as running
  `advice-add` with a changed `lambda` will be recognized as new
  advice, not as an update to the old one).

*Side remark* The `#'function` notation is basically equivalent to
 `'function`, except that it help the byte compiler identify symbols
 as function names and thus to identify missing functions (e.g. due to
 typos).

Comment: As per the [discussion](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-06/msg00308.html) I had with Stephen Monnier, hash-quotes should not be used here in all arguments.. it should be `(advice-add 'find-file :around #'my-find-file-advice-print-arguments)` and similarly `(advice-remove 'find-file #'my-find-file-advice-print-arguments)`.

Comment: I guess `advice-add` is a border case. Personally I consider the `' ↔ #'` distinction as mostly a help to identify typos in function names, so here it would probably depend on whether one expects the function to be defined by the time the advice is added.

Comment: @kdb I eventually found this out for myself (after I ran into the docs for `add-function`). I wish the docs made that clearer. I might look to making a patch for it.

Comment: @kdb Do you mean "It shows up in `C-h f find-file`, not `C-x`?

Comment: @Peeja Yes, corrected it.