# Rewriting `defadvice' as `advice-add' makes advice ineffective

Tags: init-file, advice, undo-tree-mode, apply, nadvice

I am trying to make `undo-tree` auto compress the history save file. The [document](http://www.dr-qubit.org/undo-tree/undo-tree.txt) suggests adding the following advice

```
(defadvice undo-tree-make-history-save-file-name
    (after undo-tree activate)
  (setq ad-return-value (concat ad-return-value ".gz")))
```

This works as expected, but `defadvice` is now obsolete, so I want rewrite this piece of code with `advice-add`. Here is what I've done

```
(defun undo-tree-advice-history-save-file-name (history-save-file-name)
    (concat history-save-file-name ".gz"))
(advice-add #'undo-tree :filter-return #'undo-tree-advice-history-save-file-name)
```

This doesn't produce any error or warning, but it has no effect: save files were not compressed into a `.gz` archive, but were left as plain text files instead. So I took [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14827/14867) as reference and tried

```
(defun undo-tree-advice-history-save-file-name (old-function &rest arguments)
    (concat (apply old-function arguments) ".gz"))
(advice-add #'undo-tree :around #'undo-tree-advice-history-save-file-name)
```

Again, this advice is ignored. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> (advice-add #'undo-tree :filter-return #'undo-tree-advice-history-save-file-name)
> ```

This advises the function `undo-tree`, whereas the `defadvice` form advises `undo-tree-make-history-save-file-name`.  The equivalent `advice-add` would be

```
(advice-add 'undo-tree-make-history-save-file-name :filter-return #'undo-tree-advice-history-save-file-name)
```