# How do you do runtime code swapping?

Tags: load, monkey-patching

Does elisp have the "runtime code swapping" feature?

mentioned in slide at 27:14
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TlEqzptWr0&t=27m14s

> > Hot code loading is the art of replacing an engine from a running car without having to stop it.

Definition of *code hot swapping* from [the PhD of Don Stewart](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwio-r7Tz8HlAhVK2KQKHV3rAJIQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Funsworks.unsw.edu.au%2Ffapi%2Fdatastream%2Funsworks%3A9098%2FSOURCE02&usg=AOvVaw0GSc9G0NMK3kCyR6Kb0RlJ):

> **Definition** Hot swapping is the replacement of existing code fragments at
>   runtime without loss of the environment (state) associated with that code.

Further below he explains:

> The goal of code hot swapping is to allow for upgrades to components
>   without observable loss in availability.

Comment: Please explain what "runtime code swapping" is.

Comment: aka Hot code loading -  is the art of replacing an engine from a running car without having to stop it.

Comment: The question is unclear. No one should need to follow a link to read something or watch something, to try to figure out what you might be asking. Please make the question self-explanatory.

Comment: [The link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TlEqzptWr) is useless for me. I get a "Video unavailable" error. (Maybe this is country code dependent. Don't know.) The [PhD of Don Stewart](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwio-r7Tz8HlAhVK2KQKHV3rAJIQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Funsworks.unsw.edu.au%2Ffapi%2Fdatastream%2Funsworks%3A9098%2FSOURCE02&usg=AOvVaw0GSc9G0NMK3kCyR6Kb0RlJ) descibes "hot swapping of an entire application's code". Does that fit your problem?

Comment: fixed dead link.

Comment: I hope you are okay with the definition I cited from the [PhD of Don Stewart](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwio-r7Tz8HlAhVK2KQKHV3rAJIQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Funsworks.unsw.edu.au%2Ffapi%2Fdatastream%2Funsworks%3A9098%2FSOURCE02&usg=AOvVaw0GSc9G0NMK3kCyR6Kb0RlJ). Revert if you aren't.

Comment: The answer is "yes, obviously" which is why the question is hard to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, at any point you can redefine a function by evaluating a `defun` with the name of an existing function.

By extension, when you reload a file with `M-x load-file`, all function definitions in that file will be reevaluated, and the corresponding old function definitions replaced.

If you want to change the behaviour of an existing function, it might be cleaner to "advise" that function using `advice-add` instead of redefining it.  See [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14827/11) for a description of how to do this.

Comment: `nadvice` is preferable. You should add a note about that.

Comment: @Tobias Good point, added.

Comment: Beware of inlined functions (section 13.13 of the elisp manual): "if you change the definition of the function, calls already inlined still use the old definition until you recompile them."

Comment: Nowadays one needs to regard the lexical environment of functions defined by `defun`. Therefore the answer is not so simple anymore. See my answer. I have not seen it so far but in principle one could introduce a namespace for a package through encapsulating the `defun`s into a `let`-binding. But, in that case the functions defined in the package become stateful and therefore impure. (See my answer.) I know that this disregards current guidelines for Emacs lisp packages.

Answer (score 3):

There is no real definition in Dave Thomas' video presentation.
Therefore I stick to the definition [Don Stewart gives in his PhD](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwio-r7Tz8HlAhVK2KQKHV3rAJIQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=http://unsworks.unsw.edu.au/fapi/datastream/unsworks:9098/SOURCE02&usg=AOvVaw0GSc9G0NMK3kCyR6Kb0RlJ) cited in your question.

Dave Thomas mentiones in his video that a functional language "potentially allows runtime code swapping" because "it is pure".

The notion of a pure function means that the function does not have an internal state.
The arguments of the function completely determine its output. That would fit nicely to Don's definition.

It also gives a hint how your question must be answered: The answer is: "**Yes and No** depending on the code."

## Yes

### Function definitions

Nowadays one is encouraged to use lexical binding.

Let us define a function `f` on lexical top-level.
In the following Elisp code fragments the evaluation results are given in the comments following the Elisp forms.

```el
(defun f (x)
  "Pure function"
  (1+ x))
;; f

(symbol-function 'f)
;; (closure (t) (x) "Pure function" (1+ x))
```

The lexical environment does just hold a `t` which is the symbol standing for "true" and evaluating to itself. The closure holds no state at all and we have a pure function which can be replaced by binding `f`'s function cell to another (pure) closure.

If we consider the contents of the value cells of all symbols as the current state of the Elisp runtime then swapping the pure function does not change the state of the Elisp runtime.

Note: Here we completely ignore that the function cells of the symbols actually also contribute to the state of the runtime. But that is also covered by Don's definition because the values of the function cells more or less represent the code fragments whose Don is speaking of.

### Library reloading

Symbols for variables of a library should be declared as special by `defvar` on top-level of the library. A default value can be passed as argument to `defvar`. The value cell of the dynamic variable is is only bound to the given default value if it is not yet bound, i.e., it is not set yet.

If only `devar` and `defun` are used on top-level of the library and no `setq` or function evaluation then the state of the library is even preserved when one reloads the library with `(load-file "someLibName.el")` or `(load-library "someLibName.el")`.

Thereby, the newly loaded library can also be a modified version of the first-loaded one. Naturally, it should use its dynamic variables in a compatible way.

## No

### Function definitions

Closures get a lexical environment with lexically bound symbols if they are defined in the context of a (nontrivial) `let`-binding.

If one redefines the closure in a separate evaluation of the (same) `let` form the newly defined closure has a fresh lexical environment.
It can no longer access the lexical bindings from the first evaluation of the `let` binding.

That means that closures with nontrivial lexical environment have an internal state and that state is lost if one redefines the closure through reevaluation of the `let` form.

The following code demonstrates the effect:

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(defun my-definitions ()
  (let ((state 1))

    (defun my-set-state (x)
      (setq state x))

    (defun my-get-state ()
      state)))
;; my-definitions

(my-definitions)
;; my-get-state
(defalias 'my-save-fun (symbol-function 'my-set-state))
;; my-save-fun

(my-definitions)
;; my-get-state

(symbol-function 'my-save-fun)
;; (closure ((state . 1) t) (x) (setq state x))

(symbol-function 'my-set-state)
;; (closure ((state . 1) t) (x) (setq state x))
(symbol-function 'my-get-state)
;; (closure ((state . 1) t) nil state)
(eq (cadr (symbol-function 'my-set-state)) (cadr (symbol-function 'my-get-state)))
;; t ;; `my-set-state' and `my-get-state' have the same lexical environment
(eq (cadr (symbol-function 'my-set-state)) (cadr (symbol-function 'my-save-fun)))
;; nil ;; `my-save-fun' and `my-get-state' look very alike but they have differing lexical environments
(my-save-fun 2)
;; 2 ;; setting state of `my-save-fun' to 2
(my-get-state)
;; 1 ;; state of `my-get-state' remains 1
(my-set-state 3)
;; 3 ;; set state of `my-set-state' and `my-get-state' to 3
(my-get-state)
;; 3 ;; Voila...
```

### Library reloading

If one sets the value of dynamically bound variables in a library with `setq` its previously set value is lost.
Thus reloading such a library destroys the state of the runtime.

Needless to say that function evaluation on top-level of a library can also modify the values of the dynamic variables of the library.