# Kill a line deletes the line but leaves a blank newline character

Tags: editing, kill-ring

On deleting a line in Emacs using <kbd>C-k</kbd>, Emacs removes the line contents but it leaves a blank newline character. To remove this, I again press <kbd>C-k</kbd>.

How can I delete the complete line with no traces left behind in one shot?

Comment: Related: [Kill or copy current line with minimal keystrokes](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2347/504)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From documentation:

> kill-whole-line is an interactive compiled Lisp function.
>
> It is bound to `<C-S-backspace>`.
>
> (kill-whole-line &optional ARG)
>
> Kill current line. With prefix ARG, kill that many lines starting from
>   the current line. If ARG is negative, kill backward.  Also kill the
>   preceding newline. (This is meant to make C-x z work well with
>   negative arguments.) If ARG is zero, kill current line but exclude the
>   trailing newline.

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding `(setq kill-whole-line t)` to your configuration in case you'd want it to be default behavior.

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Use 1 as argument, for example `C-1 C-k` or bind to a function that calls `(kill-whole-line 1)`.